# Highlighting a Cell if its data appears on another file entirely

Tags: google-apps-script, compare, highlight

Working specifically with VIN (Which is personal data, so please excuse me if I can't share the sheets in question) I'm trying to either have an On-Edit function, or a script tied to a button, but I'm trying to write one that can highlight all VIN on one worksheet, if it's been recorded on another.

I'm new at GAS, and am trying to grasp some of these higher concepts that I've taken and am trying to adapt for my own needs.

VIN are in Column B (aside from B1: Header), and will vary anywhere from 30-400+ to be checked, on the Data range (Active Sheet)

Marketing Range are in Column C(Starting at C4) and will vary as well, with potential of 1000+ entries.

Looking to break free from paid apps with what I initially thought was a simple function....

**EDIT: I forgot to actually pose the question**
I'm getting this:

```
`Error  
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRow')
isInRange   @ Audit.gs:31
SpeedAudit  @ Audit.gs:9`
```

I need help figuring out a fix.

```
`function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var s22 = SpreadsheetApp.openByID('XXX');
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Current Month");
  // Define ranges to only continue the function when edited cell is in there
  // This is to prevent unnecessary execution time as we have quotas
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B300");
  var marketingRange = sheet2.getRange("C4:C1000");
  
  // if edited cell is in data or marketing range
  if(isInRange(e.range, dataRange) || isInRange(e.range, marketingRange)) {
    var data = sheet.getRange("B2:B300").getValues();
    // To filter only non blank cells, add filter(Boolean)
    var marketing = sheet2.getRange("C4:C1000").getValues().flat().filter(Boolean);

    data.forEach(function (row, i) {
      row.forEach(function (cell, j) {
        if (marketing.includes(cell))
          sheet.getRange(i + 2, j + 2).setBackground("red");
        // set to white if it turns out the value is not found
        else
          sheet.getRange(i + 2, j + 2).setBackground("white");
      });
    });
  }
}

function isInRange(cell, range) {
  var startRow = range.top;
  var endRow = range.bottom;
  var startColumn = range.left;
  var endColumn = range.right;
  return cell.getRow() >= startRow && cell.getRow() <= endRow &&
         cell.getColumn() >= startColumn && cell.getColumn() <= endColumn;
}`
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You know, that probably would've helped from the get-go!

I'm getting this; clearly not grasping proper use of the function.

Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRow')
isInRange @ Audit.gs:31
SpeedAudit @ Audit.gs:9

Comment: Works OK for me.

Comment: **Troubleshooting**: insert a new line `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` at line 1 of `onEdit(e)`, trigger the script so that it returns the error message, report here with the output of the Logger statement. **Why?** because you haven't provided any sample data, you told us what the edited value was nor the edited cell(s), etc. If that isn't productive, then you will have to provide a spreadsheet that can be used to recreate your error. I appreciate the VIN may be private but no-one wants you to disclose private data -  you just replace it with dummy data that gives the same error.

Comment: @Tedinoz You're not wrong; I've gone ahead and drafted up some dummy data and sheets to test with. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u1CWMY2Al3QTV9ECvY14KtXBcT6-e-I6_QsyUPbeT2Q/edit?usp=sharing 

as the sheet I'm looking to highlight matched data that appears on 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EjwbItGDj-70g-BYaMUAIFAAIjflpZgaS38kr0syn2U/edit?usp=sharing

In hindsight I think I may just tie to a button to click, instead of trying to be 'on edit'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely to be many ways to answer this question, including both script and formula. This script is:

- run from a custom menu (`Vin Utilities`)
- is bound to the `tracker` sheet
- requires the user to insert the ID of their `marketing sheet`
- clears Column D of any `match` notes
- uses `indexOf` to find matches between each marketing VIN and the Tracker VINs
- where any VIN on `marketing` is matched with a VIN on `tracker`, the tracker row is highlighted in red with the text value "Match".

---

**RESULTS**

[image: snapshot]

---

```
    function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
          .addItem('Find VIN match from Marketing', 'vinTest')
          .addSeparator()
          .addToUi();
    }
    
    function vinTest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var trackerSheetName = "Ben"
  var tracker = ss.getSheetByName(trackerSheetName)
  
  // number of headers
  var tNumHeaders=1

  // Vin Data is in ColB (2) starting Row 2
  var bVals = tracker.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var bLast = bVals.filter(String).length;

  // clear column D (where matches are shown)
  var trackMatchCol = 4
  var trackMatchRange = tracker.getRange(2,4,bLast,1).clear()

  // get the VIN Data
  var trackVinRange = tracker.getRange(2,2,bLast,1)
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the Tracker vinRange = "+trackVinRange.getA1Notation())
  var trackVinValues = trackVinRange.getValues()
  var trackVinData = trackVinValues.flat()

  // get the Marketing data
  var marketingSheetName = "Sheet1"
  var marketingID = "1WPtF52NqV7Y-o25rBr__Lu8TZgVHgYn9R8rCHBEyiQ0"
  var marketing = SpreadsheetApp.openById(marketingID).getSheetByName(marketingSheetName)
  var mNumHeaders = 3

  // Vin Data is in ColC (3) starting Row 4
  var cVals = marketing.getRange("C4:C").getValues();
  var cLast = cVals.filter(String).length;

  // get the VIN Data
  var marktVinRange = marketing.getRange(4,3,cLast,1)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the Marketing vinRange = "+marktVinRange.getA1Notation())
  var marktVinData = marktVinRange.getValues().flat()

  // loop thought the VIN on Marketing and find matches on Tracking
  for (i=0;i<marktVinData.length;i++){
    var indexresult = trackVinData.indexOf(marktVinData[i])
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+" VIN:"+marktVinData[6]+", result = "+indexresult)
    if(indexresult != -1){ // -1 = no match
      var row = indexresult+1+tNumHeaders // zero-based plus header row
      // set the tracking colum highlight in red
      tracker.getRange(row,4,1,1).setValue("Match").setFontColor("white").setBackground("red").setFontWeight("bold")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Magnificent! Not gonna lie, the Custom Menu feature is one I hadn't studied up on yet. 

This is much cleaner than what I was trying to build. Much obliged

Comment: The only thing I'm running into, running that on the dummy sheets, is that the 'Match' cell goes all over the place when I test by putting the match in a different row. I'll have to spend some time tweaking it to lock that down, and will be testing for multiple matched VIN. This is a huge help

Comment: Argh. Mea culpa. There was an error in the very last line; I've corrected it. should read: `tracker.getRange(row,4,1,1).setValue("Match").setFontColor("white").setBackground("red").setFontWeight("bold")`

Comment: Fantastic! A little `var shtName = Browser.inputBox("Check Which Sheet?")` allowed me to set it up for multiple Agents to check their trackers against the main marketing sheet. 
Your knowledge has been invaluable; thanks again!